# How can I use git as an intermediate code review stage before pushing out the remote subversion?

Tags: svn, git, git-svn

I would like to be able to review code checked into the internal subversion repository before pushing those changes to the remote subversion server. How can I use git to stage the development subversion for review?

I have already fetched the internal subversion into git on my machine. How do I now push the changes into the remote subversion server?

Update: I am looking for a solution that allows me to pull from one subversion repository, review the code and push into a different subversion repository. Is this possible with git-svn?

Comment: Could you clarify? Are you using two separate svn servers?

Comment: @Ken: Yes. I am using two different servers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [git-svn manpage](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-svn):

```
--svn-remote <remote name>

Specify the [svn-remote "<remote name>"] section to use, 
this allows multiple SVN repositories to be tracked. Default: "svn"
```

So add your second SVN server to your `.git/config` as a new `[svn-remote]` stanza. You can then use this option to reference it.

Comment: How would I go about doing the merge and then the commit back into the svn repository?

Answer (score 2):

Go take a look at [creating patches with Git](https://rails.lighthouseapp.com/projects/8994/sending-patches).

Answer (score 0):

Why not just have one SVN repository with a development branch and a "blessed" branch where you merge the approved revisions to?